# Labeling x and y axes from imported data in R ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have two sets of imported data I want plotted on the same graph:

```
Set1
1  foo 50
2  bar 30
3  spa 70

Set2
1  foo 0.06
2  bar 0.001
3  spa 0.5
```

I want the set1 numbers plotted along the x axis (so, ranging from 0 to 100) and the set2 numbers plotted along the y (ranging from 0 to 1), with foo, bar, and spa as labeled points. I think the way to get the labeled points is:

```
ggplot(set1, aes(label = rownames(set1)))
```

All the explanations I've found have described setting two y axes, not one x and one y.

Comment: First you need to merge `Set1` and `Set2` so you can assign `x` and `y` coordinates for same point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A graph can be drawn joining both `Set1` and `Set2`. I have used `dplyr` package to join both dataframes. But I have added a column as "Name".

```
Set1 <- read.table(text = "Name X
foo 50
bar 30
spa 70", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Set2 <- read.table(text = "Name Y
foo 0.06
bar 0.001
spa 0.5", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- Set1 %>% inner_join(Set2, by = "Name")

ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: loading `dplyr` is unnecessary in this case since the [`merge`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) function exists: `merge(Set1, Set2, by = 'Name')`

Comment: @bouncyball Agree. `merge` will be sufficient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
df_test <- data.frame(set = c("foo", "bar", "spa"), x= c(50, 30, 70), y= c(0.06, 0.001, 0.5))
ggplot(df_test, aes(x=x, y=y, label = set)) + geom_point() + geom_label()
```